# How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

have a group of buttons that should act like toggle buttons, but also as radio buttons where only one button can be selected / pressed down at a current time. It also need to have a state where none of the buttons are selected / pressed down.

The behavior will be kind of like Photoshop toolbar, where zero or one of the tools are selected at any time!

Any idea how this can be implemented in Windows 8.

Is it possible to style the toggle button to act like radio button?

I am not looking for a solution like binding IsChecked Property. I need this to implement through editing the style of button.

Comment: yes, it's possible to change the style of Toggle button to act like Radio button. but, what i think is you can only modify the style of toggle button to show 2 radio button. because toggle button have only two state (like On or Off).

Comment: It's possible to style a toggle button like a radio button, yes, but the necessary functionality seems to be the radio functionality. Why not style a radio button like a toggle button?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyRadioStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxAndRadioButtonTextPaddingThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxAndRadioButtonMinWidthSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Container"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="Container">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="CheckMark" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>

    <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" IsChecked="True" Content="One" Style="{StaticResource MyRadioStyle}" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Two" Style="{StaticResource MyRadioStyle}" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Three" Style="{StaticResource MyRadioStyle}" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Four" Style="{StaticResource MyRadioStyle}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Grouping is not working... Now i can select every radio button. I need to select one at a time.